# $A\cap B\neq\varnothing \Longleftrightarrow \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\neq\varnothing ?$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ be two **non-empty** subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Is the following equivalence true
>   $$A\cap B\neq\varnothing \Longleftrightarrow \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\neq\varnothing ?$$
>   Here $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.

Since $A\cap B\subset \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$, then $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$ implies $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take$$A=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\operatorname{Im}z>0\}\text{ and }B=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\operatorname{Im}z<0\}.$$Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $\overline A\cap\overline B=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

The $\implies$ direction is correct, as you have shown.

Hint: consider $A=\{0\}$ and $B=(0,1]$ as a counterexample for the $\Longleftarrow$ direction